# how to setup --max-http-header-size with webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, https

I'm trying to setup my webpack instance with webpack-dev-server.
I pass into scripts a setting for increase header size "--max-http-header-size=100000".

```
"dev": "npm run options-to-dev && env targets=manager && node --max-http-header-size=100000 webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --progress --config webpack.config.js"
```

on execution script "dev" I got an error

```
$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
  ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

without "node --max-http-header-size=100000" webpack working perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in my file webpack-dev-server file. I pass instead `webpack-dev-server` this line `../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`

```
 "dev:windows": "npm run options-to-dev && env targets=customer && node --max-http-header-size=100000 ../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --host 0.0.0.0 --progress --config webpack.config.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me some time to figure out. Its essential not a problem with webpack devserver, nuxt or other framework running on top.

Its node that enforces the limit due to avoiding DDOS attacks for any webserver running on a node.

You can when starting node giving the argument --max-http-header-size to change the value.

But many of us that use a framework, react, or nuxt on top is not starting node ourserlf so it is hard to find exactly what to do and having to start everything ourselves is not trivial.

cross-env is really nice, allowing you to set environment variables and node do accept a NODE_OPTIONS environment variable where custom arguments all can be set.

See the example I used o a nuxt project here:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt-ts build",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=200000 DEBUG='express:*' authority=.... resourceApi=... nuxt-ts --port 3001",
    "generate": "nuxt-ts generate",
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "start": "nuxt-ts start --port 3001"
  },
```

where I changed the normal dev:"nuxt-ts" option to use cross-env and setting max HTTP header.

Hopefully, this can help others.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run `webpack-dev-server` with that option then use following:

```js
{
  "scripts": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=100000' webpack-dev-server"
}
```

A little mention about it can be found at the bottom of this documentation page: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

Hard to find without using search option ;)